Microsoft (R) VS Standard Collector Exception
According to the page Measure application performance from the command line, I issued the following two commands in a command prompt on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 installed:
> cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector"
> VSDiagnostics.exe start 1 /attach:28240 /loadConfig:AgentConfigs\CPUUsageLow.json

But I get the following error:
Microsoft (R) VS Standard Collector

The file exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070050)
   at DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Host.Interop.IStandardCollectorService.CreateSession(SessionConfiguration& sessionConfig, IStandardCollectorClientDelegate clientDelegate)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.CollectorActions.Start(RuntimeOptions options, ICollectorHost collectorHost)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()

The first time, the command succeeded, and I collected the data with the command:
VSDiagnostics.exe stop 1 /output:C:\temp\VSDiagnostics.diagsession

The second time, I left it running longer, and because VSDiagnostics.exe stop took a lot of time, I pressed Ctrl-C and stopped it. Since then, I get the above error. I deleted C:\temp\VSDiagnostics.diagsession but the error persists. There is probably somewhere a temporary file, does somebody know where that could be?
